# Why does GDB say that this address is being called

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, x86-64, att

I made a very simple C program to print "hello world" to the screen. But in the disassembly, I noticed something strange.

test.c:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    write(1, "hello, world\n", 14);
    exit(0);
}
```

First, I compile with `gcc ./test.c` and get the binary `a.out`. Perfectly normal.

Then I launch gdb with `gdb ./a.out` and set the first breakpoint to `_start` with `b _start`

I type `r` and dissasemble the `_start` function with `disass`

My start function looks like this:

```
Dump of assembler code for function _start:
=> 0x0000555555555050 <+0>:     endbr64 
   0x0000555555555054 <+4>:     xor    %ebp,%ebp
   0x0000555555555056 <+6>:     mov    %rdx,%r9
   0x0000555555555059 <+9>:     pop    %rsi
   0x000055555555505a <+10>:    mov    %rsp,%rdx
   0x000055555555505d <+13>:    and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
   0x0000555555555061 <+17>:    push   %rax
   0x0000555555555062 <+18>:    push   %rsp
   0x0000555555555063 <+19>:    lea    0x176(%rip),%r8        # 0x5555555551e0 <__libc_csu_fini>
   0x000055555555506a <+26>:    lea    0xff(%rip),%rcx        # 0x555555555170 <__libc_csu_init>
   0x0000555555555071 <+33>:    lea    0xd1(%rip),%rdi        # 0x555555555149 <main>
   0x0000555555555078 <+40>:    call   *0x2f62(%rip)        # 0x555555557fe0
   0x000055555555507e <+46>:    hlt
```

In _start+40 we're calling `*0x2f62(%rip)`, but not main? Even stranger, I type `x/20i 0x555555557fe0` to disassemble this mystery address and get:

```
   0x555555557fe0:      rex push %rbx
   0x555555557fe2:      fdiv   %st,%st(7)
   0x555555557fe4:      (bad)  
   0x555555557fe5:      jg     0x555555557fe7
   0x555555557fe7:      add    %al,(%rax)
   0x555555557fe9:      add    %al,(%rax)
   0x555555557feb:      add    %al,(%rax)
   0x555555557fed:      add    %al,(%rax)
   0x555555557fef:      add    %al,(%rax)
   0x555555557ff1:      add    %al,(%rax)
   0x555555557ff3:      add    %al,(%rax)
   0x555555557ff5:      add    %al,(%rax)
   0x555555557ff7:      add    %al,-0x30(%rax)
   0x555555557ffa:      (bad)  
   0x555555557ffc:      (bad)  
   0x555555557ffd:      jg     0x555555557fff
   0x555555557fff:      add    %bh,%al
   0x555555558001:      cmp    $0x0,%eax
   0x555555558006:      add    %al,(%rax)
   0x555555558008:      movabs 0xd000007ffff7ffe2,%al
```

how odd. I typed `b *0x0000555555555078`, to set a breakpoint at where `_start` calls this, and the an `si`, but instead of being at `0x555555557fe0`, I wound up at `0x00007ffff7dc5340 in __libc_start_main_impl () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6`.

Can anyone explain to me what's going on here? Is this a common thing, or is my GDB acting up?

Comment: I believe the `add %al,(%rax)` instruction is a bunch of `0`s in machine code (I don’t have an x86_64 machine available right now). The memory at that location is probably not a code segment and not meant to be executed. Perhaps GDB’s comment is incorrect?

Comment: You are missing a level of indirection. Notice the `*` in the `call *0x2f62(%rip)`. The memory at address `0x555555557fe0` is a pointer. Do `x/a 0x555555557fe0` that should then give you `0x00007ffff7dc5340` which is where the control is transferred to. Also notice that the preceding line loads the address of `main` into `rdi` which is then passed to the `__libc_start_main_impl` as an argument so that will in turn call it.

Comment: @tjcaul I thought that at first too, but the objdump gives the same address with `add al, rax`

Comment: @Jester Oh, i think i get it. the address in the call is the location of data, not executable code?

Comment: Yes, gdb just calculates the `0x2f62(%rip)` value for you. It is a pointer due to the `*`. gdb does not fetch the pointer for you.

Comment: In C terms, 0x555555557fe0 is the address of a function pointer, not the function itself.

Answer (score 4):

*Disclaimer: This answer is partially based on the comments of others.*

The instruction in question:

```
call *0x2f62(%rip)
```

does three things:

1. Calculate the address (add `0x2f62` to the value of register `rip`). Since the instruction pointer (`rip`) will always be `0x000055555555507e` at this point (the end of the instruction), GDB knows that the result of the addition will be `0x555555557fe0`
2. Dereference the address (get the value at the address `0x555555557fe0`). This is indicated by the `*`
3. Call the function at the new address.

This is loading from memory into RIP, a memory-indirect call.  That's why there's a memory addressing mode in the disassembly, instead of just a target address.

Consider this example in C:

```
int func (int n) {
    //do something
}

int main (void) {
    int (*ptr)(int) = &func;

    (*ptr)(5); //The instruction in question is equivalent to this line
}
```

So the program execution does not continue at address `0x555555557fe0`; it continues at the address *stored* at `0x555555557fe0`.

This is probably the GOT entry for `__libc_start_main`, set by the dynamic linker before `_start` from the main executable even runs.  `__libc_start_main` is in libc.so, so `_start` can't reach it directly with a `call rel32`, because it might be too far away, and because the distance isn't a link-time constant.

---

I was quite confused by this when disassembling a similar program. It's easy to miss this intricacy if you aren't familiar with AT&T assembly syntax.

Comment: RIP-relative addressing is relative to the *end* of the current instruction. 
RIP will always be 0x000055555555507e, not ...78 , when the `0x2f62(%rip)` addressing mode is evaluated.  That's why the final address actually is `0x555555557fe0`.  (e+2 = 0, 8+2 = a).  But yes, it's calling through a function pointer, probably in the GOT, probably to `__libc_start_main` in libc.so, which is why it needs that indirection in the first place.  (`gcc -fno-plt` style asm, not going through the PLT.)  Oh, yes the question confirms that single-stepping got to that symbol name.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited my post to match. I had temporarily forgotten that `rip` holds the value of the *next* instruction.

Answer (score 3):

> In _start+40 we're calling *0x2f62(%rip), but not main?

Note that `_start` usually doesn't call `main` -- there is *a lot of code* which executes between `_start` and `main` even in a statically linked binary.

In a dynamically linked binary (such as yours) there will be many thousands of instructions before you finally enter `main`.

> Even stranger, I type x/20i 0x555555557fe0 to disassemble this mystery address and get:

This is an *indirect* call. The instructions you want to disassemble are at whatever address `x/a 0x555555557fe0` prints (it should print `0x00007ffff7dc5340 __libc_start_main`).

> Is this a common thing, or is my GDB acting up?

It's a common thing.

If you really want to understand what's happening at startup, start with a statically linked non-PIE binary (`gcc -static -no-pie test.c`) -- it has simpler startup sequence.

After you understand what happens there, progress to dynamically linked non-PIE binary (`gcc -no-pie test.c`), and then finally to dynamically linked PIE (which is what your GCC produces by default).